# Can the tilde (~) Web application root operator be changed without access to iis?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm uploading a website to a subfolder on a remote server. The root folder is defined as an application, and has its own web.config file.

The server uses iis7 but I don't have access to it, is it possible to define the root web application operator (~) in the subfolder webconfig file, or any other way without access to iis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this IS with access to IIS (or the hosting provider's control panel) by setting up the subfolder as a virtual directory or application.  Unfortunately, I believe that by definition, the tilde is a shortcut for the application root (see [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath.aspx)).

Comment: ahh ok, so it works as designed. hmm i guess i will have to change all of my ~ for something else then... Thanks for taking the time to respond.